# Email body is sent in a file [Gmail API, Node.js]

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

I have tried to use the [Gmail API Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client), but the email body is sent in a file attachment. Everything else is working properly (from, to, subject, etc.).

The original code of my problem can be seen [here](https://github.com/iago-mendes/cruz-server/blob/master/src/services/gmail/index.ts), but the following is a simpler example of what I am trying to do:

```js
import {google} from 'googleapis'

const accessToken = 'token created using google OAuth2 from googleapis package' // this is working properly, so I won't include the code here

async function sendMail(subject: string, text: string, to: string, from: string)
{
    const utf8Subject = `=?utf-8?B?${Buffer.from(subject).toString('base64')}?=`
    const messageParts =
    [
        `From: ${from}`,
        `To: ${to}`,
        'Content-Type: text/html charset=utf-8',
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        `Subject: ${utf8Subject}`,
        '',
        text,
    ]
  
    const message = messageParts.join('\n')
    const encodedMessage = Buffer.from(message)
        .toString('base64')
        .replace(/\+/g, '-')
        .replace(/\//g, '_')
        .replace(/=+$/, '')

  const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth: accessToken})

  await gmail.users.messages.send(
  {
    userId: 'me',
    requestBody:
    {
      raw: encodedMessage,
    }
  })
}

sendMail('Some subject', 'Some text', 'to@example.com', 'from@example.com')
```

The email received by `to` has no body, and the `text` variable somehow turns into a file. When using `text/html`, this file has the extension `.html`.

I tried to find some tag like `Body:` or `HTML:`, but I could not find any. Looking at the [official example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/gmail/send.js), I don't understand what is the problem with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your header, `;` is required to be used as the separator between `Content-Type` and `charset`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
'Content-Type: text/html charset=utf-8',
```

#### To:

```
'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
```

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that `const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth: accessToken})` can be used for sending an email. Please be careful this.